# Jest Typescript with ES Module in node_modules error - Must use import to load ES Module:

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, es6-modules

I'm trying to write a simple jest test for a 3rd party package were using that only exports an ES module. It's a wrapper around an `http` server.

Here is a test repo I setup (just run `yarn && yarn jest` to reproduce): https://github.com/jamesopti/hocuspocus-testing

No matter what config I experiment with, I still get this error when trying to run it:

```sh
 Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/j/hocuspocus-testing/node_modules/@hocuspocus/server/dist/hocuspocus-server.esm.js

    > 1 | import { Server, Hocuspocus } from '@hocuspocus/server'
        | ^
      2 | import * as request from 'supertest'
      3 |
      4 | describe('Server (e2e)', () => {
```

**Things I've tried already:**

- The Jest instructions on ES modules: https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules
- In Jest configuration using `transformIgnorePatterns`

  - `transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@hocuspocus/)']`
- Using Babel via `babel-jest`

  - modifying transform setup in Jest configuration as '^.+\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest', '^.+\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  - Ran into the error `You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously.`
  - Using .babel.config.js instead of .babelrc.js

Any ideas what I'm missing here? I thought this would be straightforward

**[EDIT 1]** - Added `tsconfig.json` and a working `src/index.ts` file to [the example repo](https://github.com/jamesopti/hocuspocus-testing).

Answer (score 25):

So for anyone still hitting this, ESM configuration explained in this section of documentation :

https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support

```
{
  // [...]
  "jest": {
    "extensionsToTreatAsEsm": [".ts"],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "useESM": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You may also want to add ` "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$": "$1"
    }` as well as noted in https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/

Comment: As of Jan 2023 there's a new syntax by @BigMan73 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75001235/122441

Answer (score 17):

JAN 2023: ES2022, TypeScript 4.9.4, jest 29.3.1, ts-jest 29.0.3
FEB 2024: Modified transform file regex based on comment from @vick

This is what worked for me, after 2 hours of frustration.
I used this configuration in `jest.config.ts`:

```typescript
import type { JestConfigWithTsJest } from 'ts-jest'

const config: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
  verbose: true,
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': ['ts-jest', { useESM: true }]
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['./dist']
}

export default config
```

Change the `test` script in `package.json` to:

> I use `pnpm`. Change to `npx jest` with npm,
> or `yarn exec` with yarn

```json
...
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules pnpm exec jest",
  ...
}
...
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "composite": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["jest", "node", "@types/jest"],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./tests/**/*"]
}
```

See this (rather confusing) documentation for reference:
https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/

Comment: What about passing args to Jest, like specifying a config file? When I do `"itest-local": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules yarn exec jest -c jest.config.integration.ts --runInBand"`, the config doesn't get picked up.

Comment: I just tried with this command (I'm using pnpm not yarn) and it worked fine with a custom jest config file. I intentionally caused damage to the file (used a  testEnvironment: 'nodeXX', which doesn't exist), in order to test that the config file is actually being read. 

```"test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules pnpm exec jest --config local.jest.config.ts" ```

Comment: Your transform regex, `'^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$'` is not quite right. As it is it will match any file ending with a literal `.` in addition to ones ending in `.ts` and `.tsx`.

The simplest regex here is `"\\.tsx?$"` which matches what I think you intended, files ending in `.ts` or `.tsx`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a `tsconfig.json` file that specifies [`module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module). Therefore it uses the default, where it transpiles all your modules to `CommonJS` syntax, which uses `require`.

If you actually look at your `dist/hocuspocus-server.esm.js`, you should see it using `require` over the ESM import syntax.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I forgot to copy over the `tsconfig.json` from the real project (just pushed an update). I still get the same error though.

Comment: re: `dist/hocuspocus-server.esm.js`, the package is not using `require`, its all ES module import/exports. Is that an issue on the publisher's side?

Comment: Perhaps since your `tsconfig.json` only includes `src/`, `ts-node` (which iirc is what `jest` uses) might still compile your `test/` to CommonJS. I don't know the exact interaction there, but I still feel like it's an issue with the test code being transpiled to use `require`.

Answer (score 2):

Much as I'm loathe to give a "use something else" type answer, I'm going to, even though it may not directly answer the original question.

It does, however, answer the question "How can I make it easy to test my TypeScript files which have ESM dependencies, whilst using Jest syntax?"

After messing around with various `jest.config.js` options, with ideas taken from some of these answers, I eventually just did:

```
npm install -D vitest
```

... and, it all just worked. No `jest.config.js` file. No messing with any other dependencies.

The only change I had to make was to import some test-related functions that you don't have to with Jest:

```
import { expect, describe, it } from "vitest";
```

Other than this, it's easy to forget I'm not simply using Jest.

Further detail here: https://vitest.dev/guide/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with my svelte app and testing. I ultimately traced it to having a `jest.config.js` and a `jest.config.json` in my root folder. It seems that jest does not have automatic config file resolution and was using a default configuration instead of either of my specified configurations.