# Jest cannot read jest.config.ts

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs

Trying to run Jest tests on node, and I keep getting this error. Not sure how to solve it to run

```
Error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file: ../directory/jest.config.ts
Error: Must use import to load ES Module:  ../directory/jest.config.ts
require() of ES modules is not supported.
```

my `jest.config.ts`:

```
export default {
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
  transform: {},
};
```

Comment: Does this solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520619/jest-typescript-with-es-module-in-node-modules-error-must-use-import-to-load-e