# Why do only the imports of Discord.js from Jest throw an error of Must use import to load ES Module?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, discord.js, ts-jest

I'm working on Jest with Node and Discord.js, and running into some weird issues that I'm struggling to figure out. Whenever I run my tests, they mostly succeed, but fail at every import from discord.js. However, plenty of tests succeed with esm module imports from other files. Discord.js had to go through some weirdness in the jest config due to the ".js" triggering certain flags. However, I'm unsure where the configuration I need to adjust lies.

```
 Details: 
FAIL  src/utils/foo.spec.ts (12.059 s)
  ● Foo › Foo › some description

    Must use import to load ES Module: /home/kobold/Documents/kobold/node_modules/undici/lib/llhttp/llhttp.wasm

    > 1 | import { EmbedBuilder } from 'discord.js';
        | ^
      2 | import { Bar } from '../services/bar/index.js';
      3 | import { Foo } from './Foo.js';
      4 |
```

This is the jest config I'm using:

```js
import type { InitialOptionsTsJest } from 'ts-jest/dist/types';

const jestOptions: InitialOptionsTsJest = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.ts'],
    transform: {
        '\\.[jt]sx?$': [
            'ts-jest',
            {
                useESM: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        'discord.js': 'discord.js',
        '(.+)\\.js': '$1',
    },
    modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['discord.js'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts', '.json'],
    clearMocks: true,
};
export default jestOptions;
```

And this is the tsconfig I'm using:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2021",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "lib": ["es2021"],
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": false,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "disableSizeLimit": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.json", "types.d.ts"],
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "migrations",
        "node_modules",
        "tests",
        "jest.config.ts",
        "jest.setup.ts",
        "knexfile.ts"
    ]
}
```

The first thing I did was to remove the discord.js import from that file, as well as the line that used the imported object. That caused the test to run just fine, despite the two other esm imports in the file.

After that, I guessed that this was due to discord.js exposing a new module style import or something, as this problem hadn't manifested in the past, despite my config not changing for months. So, I began to play with the transforms. I tried removing the ignore pattern for discord js, I tried forcing discord js to useESM true and useESM false. However, either I made a mistake with the way I input the configuration, or that wasn't the problem.

I've also gone through and tried all the solutions in this questoin: [Jest Typescript with ES Module in node_modules error - Must use import to load ES Module:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520619/jest-typescript-with-es-module-in-node-modules-error-must-use-import-to-load-e)

None of them worked. The newest answer seems close to the problem that I'm having, but I think I'm struggling because I'm still outputting to commonJS from my ts config. Changing that would be a major rewrite, and I remember I had it as commonJS because another tool (I think knex?) wasn't playing nice with esm.